# How do I preserve a host header in the browser's url after a 301 redirect?

Tags: nginx, proxy, http-status-code-301, nginx-config, hostheaders

I've got a mandate to make an internal URL (`coolnewproduct.mycoolcorp.net`) redirect to an external entity (`mycoolcorp.coolerproducts.com`). Im using nginx to perform a 301 redirect for `coolnewproduct.mycoolcorp.net` to `mycoolcorp.coolerproducts.com` however the host header visible in the browser changes and `mycoolcorp.coolerproducts.com` is seen. Is there a way for nginx to preserve the original `coolnewproduct.mycoolcorp.net` host header after performing the redirect?

Comment: It seems you need a transparent proxying, not a redirect. Can you include your current nginx config to your question? Does site `mycoolcorp.coolerproducts.com` use cookies?

Comment: ```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name coolnewproduct.mycoolcorp.net;

        root /var/www/html;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        location / {
                proxy_pass       http://mycoolcorp.coolerproducts.com/;
                proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name coolnewproduct.mycoolcorp.net;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host mycoolcorp.coolerproducts.com;
        proxy_cookie_domain mycoolcorp.coolerproducts.com coolnewproduct.mycoolcorp.net;
        proxy_pass http://mycoolcorp.coolerproducts.com;
    }
}
```

If site `mycoolcorp.coolerproducts.com` uses automatic redirection from HTTP to HTTPS, change line `proxy_pass http://mycoolcorp.coolerproducts.com;` to `proxy_pass https://mycoolcorp.coolerproducts.com;`.

**Update**

Assuming nginx compiled with a [ngx_http_sub_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html), to rewrite absolute links in a proxied site request body, you can try to use this config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name coolnewproduct.mycoolcorp.net;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    location / {
        sub_filter_once off;
        sub_filter '//mycoolcorp.coolerproducts.com/' '//coolnewproduct.mycoolcorp.net/';
        proxy_set_header Host mycoolcorp.coolerproducts.com;
        proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
        proxy_cookie_domain mycoolcorp.coolerproducts.com coolnewproduct.mycoolcorp.net;
        proxy_pass http://mycoolcorp.coolerproducts.com;
    }
}
```

I have never worked with this module, some people say it makes only one substitution per page. There is an [alternative](https://github.com/yaoweibin/ngx_http_substitutions_filter_module) from our China friends which confirmed to work for this case (never used it too).

Comment: This works and does redirect to the new site, however Im trying to preserve the original http header that I passed in...if possible.

Comment: @VladBekker Are you sure your browser do not caching a redirect from your previous config? Try this configuration from an incognito browser window to be sure.

Comment: I think this works properly, but Im missing a rewrite to make sure that all of the URI's get rewritten properly with a new hoist header. The moment you navigate on any links, you'd get a 404

Comment: So your external site uses absolute links instead of relative? Proxying such site is a non-trivial task. You can try to use a [`ngx_http_sub_module`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html), but for this you must manually compile nginx from source with a `--with-http_sub_module` configuration parameter.